# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attack' "'Help!"

Tags: python, attributes, typeerror, attributeerror, string

I have q quick question regarding an Attribute Error regarding a basic Arena battler I am writing for my Intro to Programming Class.
Here is the chunk of code that I am having trouble with upon running the program,

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self,player,weapons,armor):

        self.name = "Bad Guy" 
        self.health = 100
        self.attackPower = (player.attack + randint(-5,5))
        self.defensePower = (player.defense + randint(-5,5))
        self.weapon = player.weapon
        self.armor = player.armor
    def name_generator(self):
        import random
        element = ["Thunder","Lightning","Wind","Fire", "Stone"]
        tool = ["Hammer","Drill","Cutter","Knife", "Saw"]
        randomNumber1 = random.randrange(0,len(element))
        randomNumber2 = random.randrange(0,len(tool))
        self.randomname = element[randomNumber1] + " " + tool[randomNumber2]
        return self.randomname
```

Lol, ignore the Name Generator for now, thats an idea Ill try to work out later. The Current problem I am having now is that when I run the program through IDLE i get the following error;

```
  File "C:\Users\Caleb Walter\Downloads\Arena_Battler.py", line 150, in __init__
    self.attackPower = int(player.attack + randint(-5,5))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attack'
```

Any Help would be appreciated on the program error, as I have done research and tried to find the answer but all of the other casses of 'str' error involved lists.
Thank You in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, you are calling the constructor of this class (where you instantiate it) with player name (string) instead of a player object (with parameters 'attack','defence', etc.).

Comment: Thank you Max! So How would I go about fixing this issue, If you could be so kind :P A point in the right direction would be enough :)

Comment: I won't be up-voting this just because I suspect it's the correct answer -- since, as the author says, it's "obvious".

Comment: @Caleb W.: Take a hint from the "instead of a player object" part.

Answer (score 2):

How to read and understand error messages, so that you can help yourself:

First, we read it:

```
File "C:\Users\Caleb Walter\Downloads\Arena_Battler.py", line 150, in __init__
self.attackPower = int(player.attack + randint(-5,5))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'attack'
```

The first line says what file and line we were at when the problem occurred. The second line is a copy of the line causing the problem, so we can look at it without having to go back and look it up. The last line is a description of what the actual problem was.

Therefore, the next step is to read what the problem was. `AttributeError` means that we tried to get an attribute from something that doesn't have it. The rest says what kind of thing we tried to get it from (a `'str' object`, i.e., a string), and what we tried to get (an attribute named `attack`).

Next we look at the line in question. Where do we attempt to get an attribute named `attack` from something? Clearly, it's the part where we've written `player.attack`. Thus, we now know what happened: our code tries to get the `attack` attribute from the `player` variable, but `player` is referring to a string, and strings don't have an `attack` attribute. (Obviously; what is the `attack` of `"hi mom"` ? That doesn't make any sense.)

How did this happen? Well, if we wrote code that tries to read an `attack` attribute, clearly we must have been expecting it to be there. We don't expect such an attribute on strings, so the error is that we've put a string into `player` when we expected something else.

How does the value get into `player`? It's a parameter to the function. Therefore, we **called** it wrongly, and we go off to find the line of code where we called it (hint: **look at the previous entry in the stack-trace**), and fix the surrounding code. What were we supposed to pass? Well, something that does have an `attack`, obviously. Did you have some kind of Player class? Then you should be passing an instance of that, rather than a (the player's?) name or whatever.

Comment: Thanks Karl, that is probably the best explanation of the problem Ive seen, Very clear and informative! I have fixed the problem and eevrything works fine now!